# Better way to return a promise that resolves to a stream in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, pipeline, node-streams

I'm stuck somehow, I have something like this in my code:

```js
async function download() {

  const source = createReadStreamSomeHow();

  await pipeline(source, fs.createWriteStream("file.ext"));

  return source;
}
```

I need to return the readable stream (source) and store it in an array somewhere and at the same time pipe the data from the read stream to "file.ext". But when I call:

```js
let task = await download();
taskArray.add(task);
```

the `pipeline()` code pauses execution of the function, hence source is only returned when the data has been completely piped to "file.ext".

Although I understand why the code behaves this way, I can't seem to find a way to return the source stream from the `download()` function and still pipe the data to "file.ext" at the same time. Is there a better way to achieve this and make it work? Thank for the help in advance.

Comment: Remove `await` and should work fine

Comment: Your possibly looking for a stream multiplexer, for example this NPM module might be what your after -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/readable-file-writer

Comment: @Konrad I tried dropping the promise and the readable stream's data doesn't get piped at all and the file contains 0B of data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply drop the `async/await`

```
function download() {

  const source = createReadStreamSomeHow();

  pipeline(source, fs.createWriteStream("file.ext"));

  return source;
}
```

The Promise is still executed, but you have no info when it is done/if it throws.

Or you return the source together with the promise

```
function download() {
  const source = createReadStreamSomeHow();

  const promise = pipeline(source, fs.createWriteStream("file.ext"));

  return { source, promise }
}

// you can enqueue the source ... 
let task = download();
taskArray.add(task.source);

// ... and handle the promise however you like.
await task.promise;
```

Comment: I tried dropping the promise and the readable stream's data doesn't get piped at all and the file contains 0B of data

Comment: then this must have something to do with the rest of your code. A Promise is basically just an one-time event dispatcher for a single value, nothing more. How do you determine that nothing happened? How long do you wait before you check? Do you wait for the Promises to finish before you close the process?

Comment: Sorry, I meant, "I tried dropping the await keyword on the promise"

Comment: OK, what about `async`, and the other `await`? Either way, still doesn't explain how you determine that it doesn't work, how long (if at all) you wait for the pipeline to do its thing, or if you kill the process before it even started.

Comment: There is a `checkIfBinaryExists()` method inside the download method but it returns very quickly but that isn't a problem. I'm currently trying to use your suggestions, if it works fine, I'll upvote